# Console Output As CSV?

Tags: javascript, postman, console.log

Can Postman output in CSV?

I have postman setup the way I need with 3 requests to iterate around 40 times. Each time I print something else and currently just log to console at this time.

I want to now write this to a CSV or other more readable format. Is there a specific way to do this via postman?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const fs = require('fs')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.use(bodyParser.text());
app.post('/', (req, res) => {
  
fs.writeFileSync( "file.csv", req.body, "utf8" )
res.send("success")
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```

Create a ndoejs file with above content save its as api.js.

open cmd with the folder containing that file as current directory and run the api.js file as :

```
node api.js
```

you will get the below out put if it runs successfully

```
Example app listening at http://localhost:3000
```

**And now in yout test script in postman:**

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    newvalue = "something" // save the value you are printing to this variable eg :pm.request.json().name "
    //Adding the new values to a string as value1,value2,value3 etc
    data = i === 0 ? data = "" : data = i === 1 ? newvalue : data + "," + newvalue
}
```

//once your 40 iteration is done doing a  api call to the express api we created :

```
// Example with a full-fledged request
const postRequest = {
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/',
    method: 'POST',

    body: {
        mode: 'raw',
        raw: data
    }
};
pm.sendRequest(postRequest, (error, response) => {
    //console.log(error ? error : response.json());
});
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks! @PDHide, I ended up moving over to Python and relearn the very little I learned in postman for this.

Answer (score 1):

In order to answer your question first and foremost it's important to understand what Postman actually is:

**Postman is an API client that allows you to create simple to complex HTTP/s requests and read their responses.**

So, can you write data to an CSV file using Postman?

That's totally up to you, you can send an HTTP request to a server with data and then the server will be responsible of writing that data, but you can't actually perform such operations or write code in Postman.

You can only perform HTTP requests and then delegate that to a server that will be responsible of these kind of operations you'd like to do.

Comment: I appreciate that, I'm pretty new to the scene haha. That's helpful, so perhaps my question is not how to do that from postman, but how to achieve retrieving the same data another way that allows me to do such things. I have more experience with python and was looking into their API potential, postman just seemed to be a little easier to do it with.

Comment: Postman is mostly used to test API's, not for production use. First you want to be able to save data to a CSV format. You can do it either on client side or server side, usually it's  better to do it on the server as you can actually perform FS operations but it can be done on the client side as well. Let's assume you have that operation done on the server, now you need to create an API, I recommend you look into how to create a simple API with express, once you do that you can perform requests to the API via fetch or use a package like Axios, and you can use Postman to test the API